# Python print several (same) values

Tags: python, list, printing

I have a problem here:

```
scores = {}
with open('score.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        name, score = line.strip().rsplit(' ', 1)

        score = int(score)

        if name in scores:scores[name] = scores[name] + score

        else:scores[name] = score

sortedScoresByMax = max(scores.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])
print (sortedScoresByMax)
```

the score.txt contains several names with a score. Right now the program only prints out the one person with the highest score. But if some names have the same score, I need the program to print out all of them. I'm guessing I have to use a loop but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You're asking only for the top player (and any players tied for 1st), but you're calling it "sorted scores": would you rather have all the players sorted?

Comment: This, and you should use the common indentation practice (line break+indentation after ":")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by iterating over the `dict` object `scores`that you get at the end of your `for` loop if you know the max value.

```
maximum = max(scores.values())
for key in scores:
    if scores[key] == maximum:
        print key, scores[key]
```

Comment: This is basically David Robinsons answer, but definitely less pythonic.
@OP: are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Jasper It looks like David Robinsons and I thought the same way. But as you can see, off course they would not give you the same output. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could find the maximum value, then print all players with that score:

```
maxscore = max(scores.values())
print [(p, s) for p, s in scores.items() if s == maxscore]
```

Answer (score 1):

With just one pass over the dict:

```
maxscore=0
maxscorers = []
for name, score in scores.items():
  if score > maxscore:
    maxscore = score
    maxscorers = [name]
  elif score = maxscore:
    maxscorers.append(name)
```

I'm not sure if this is very pythonic, but I like it more than first determining the maximum and then filtering the list.

Answer (score 0):

`max()` will only return one value. You can, however, use `sorted()` with the `reverse=True` option to obtain a list of scores and names in descending order like this:

```
sortedScoresByMax = sorted(scores.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda t: t[1])
```